# The operation was throttled by the Power BI Premium because of insufficient memory

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I have a relative small model in Power BI, in the capacity report it notes only 14 GB in size.
It has 83 tables and incremental loading permitted, as well as large datasets enabled, etc.

However, simply running a refresh in a premium instance (100GB models permitted), the error always appears:

```
'The operation was throttled by the Power BI Premium because of insufficient memory. Please try again later'
```

I know the model is not that large, how can I guarantee refresh?

Comment: Is the dataset loading in parallel? try changing it to sequential, to see it that reduces the impact on the memory

Comment: Yes, I am trying to go that route, I am using this as guide: : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/sequence-command-tmsl?view=asallproducts-allversions#request, setting maxparallelism = 1

I was able to load 9 of the bigger tables doing that ,now trying all of them,
do you know of any other way to set sequential

Comment: @Jon question, by useing sequence and maxParallelism = 1, I assume that will like "load everything for one table, then compress it, then move on" correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue...there were garbage calculated columns that were exploding the dataset size that I refactored